# I cannot print my Closing Connection message after typing QUIT

Tags: java, sockets, intellij-idea

I've been using If else statements to handle `startsWith()` methods in my java server cpde, however whenever i want to `QUIT` the server by typing `QUIT` in my client, it just gives `process finished with exit code 0` in the server output.

How can i make it so when i type `quit` in my client, the server prints out

```
C: QUIT
S: 221 [IP] closing connection
```

Here is the Server.java:

```
package TCPSocket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TCPServer{
    private ServerSocket server;

    /**
     * The TCPServer constructor initiate the socket
     * @param ipAddress
     * @param port
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public TCPServer(String ipAddress, int port) throws Exception {
        if (ipAddress != null && !ipAddress.isEmpty())
            this.server = new ServerSocket(port, 1, InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress));
        else
            this.server = new ServerSocket(0, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    }

    /**
     * The listen method listen to incoming client's datagrams and requests
     * @throws Exception
     */



    private void listen() throws Exception {
        // listen to incoming client's requests via the ServerSocket
        //add your code here
        String data = null;
        Socket client = this.server.accept();
        String clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("\r\nNew client connection from " + clientAddress);


        String serverIP = "192.168.56.1"; // local IP address
        int port = 7077;

        // print received datagrams from client
        //add your code here
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        while ( (data = in.readLine()) != null && !data.equals("QUIT")) {

            try {
                if (data.startsWith("HELLO")) {
                    System.out.println("\r\nC: " + data);
                    System.out.println("\r\nS: 250" + data.toLowerCase() + ", pleased to meet you");
                } else if (data.startsWith("MAIL FROM: ")) {
                    System.out.println("\r\nC: " + data);
                    System.out.println("\r\nS: 250 ok");
                } else if (data.startsWith("RCPT TO: ")) {
                    System.out.println("\r\nC: " + data);
                    System.out.println("\r\nS: 250 ok");
                } else if (data.equals("DATA")) {
                    System.out.println("\r\nC: " + data);
                    System.out.println("\r\nS: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>");
                } else if (data.equals(".")) {
                    System.out.println("\r\nC: " + data);
                    System.out.println("\r\nS: 250 ok Message accepted for delivery");
                } else
                    System.out.println("\r\nC: " + data);

                client.sendUrgentData(1);

                server.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            
            System.out.println("\r\nC: " + data);
            System.out.println("\r\nS: 221 " + serverIP + " closing connection");
        }






    }


    public InetAddress getSocketAddress() {
        return this.server.getInetAddress();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.server.getLocalPort();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set the server address (IP) and port number
        //add your code here
        String serverIP = "192.168.56.1"; // local IP address
        int port = 7077;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            serverIP = args[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }
        // call the constructor and pass the IP and port
        //add your code here
        TCPServer server = new TCPServer(serverIP, port);
        System.out.println("\r\nRunning Server: " +
                "Host=" + server.getSocketAddress().getHostAddress() +
                " Port=" + server.getPort());
        System.out.println("220 " + serverIP);
        server.listen();
    }

}
```

Help if greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

delete

```
server.close();
```

and it will work

Comment: I don't think you want to totally remove the `server.close()`, I suspect you want to move it outside of the loop.